# Python class has no attribute when calling function

Tags: python

I have this kind of problem `attributeError: module 'ResponseLayer' has no attribute 'RS'`. I am a beginner just started learning python from scratch. What do i need to understand here? Am i wrong coding this?

```
class ResponseLayer:

    def RS(self,_width, _height, _step, _filter):
        self.width = _width
        self.height = _height
        self.step = _step
        self.filterr = _filter

class FastHessian:

    import ResponseLayer

    def buildResponseMap():
        responseMap = []

        w = int(img.Width / init)
        h = int(img.Height / init)
        s = int(init)

        if (octaves >=1):
            responseMap.append(RS(w, h, s, 9))
            responseMap.append(RS(w, h, s, 15))
            responseMap.append(RS(w, h, s, 21))
            responseMap.append(RS(w, h, s, 27))
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback? I don't see what line of the provided code would produce that error. It might also help to describe what you're trying to accomplish with this code. Some of it looks strange, but I can't tell what you should be doing instead if I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Your code does not run for several reasons (`img` and `octaves` are not defined, for example). Please [edit] your question to include enough code that we can run it. See [mcve].

Comment: `import ReponseLayer` implies you have a file named `ResponseLayer.py` somewhere, and the module is distinct from the any class by the same name that might defined in the file. Further, `RS` is a method, not a class, so it's not clear what code is generating the `AttributeError` or why you aren't getting a `NameError` on the use of `RS` you show.

Comment: You should work through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), though; your code looks like someone trying to write Java in Python, rather than real Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Ianny,

If all the code you've shown live in the same file, then you don't have to import `ResponseLayer`.

I believe you're adding unique instances of `ResponseLayer` to a response map.

If I am correct, then you should change that `RS` method on `ResponseLayer` class to an instance creation method (`init` in Python).

So that you just write `ResponseLayer(20, 30, 2, 4)` to create an example response layer object.

This is what I mean:

```
class ResponseLayer:

    def __init__(self, width, height, step, _filter):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.step = step
        self._filter = _filter

class FastHessian:

    def buildResponseMap():
        responseMap = []

        w = int(img.Width / init)
        h = int(img.Height / init)
        s = int(init)

        if (octaves >= 1):
            responseMap.append(ResponseLayer(w, h, s, 9))
            responseMap.append(ResponseLayer(w, h, s, 15))
            responseMap.append(ResponseLayer(w, h, s, 21))
            responseMap.append(ResponseLayer(w, h, s, 27))
```

I understand you are a Python beginner.

Welcome to the world of Python.

I love helping beginners level up in my areas of strength. Like @chepner mentioned, your code looks too Java for Python. I would love to help you rewrite it to be more Pythonic. Feel free to chat me up here on StackOverflow.